# Height Adoption CalendarView with Decoration

Tags: swiftui

i have a CalendarView in a SwiftUI View with a UIViewRepresentable:

I have two scenarios: 1. with the decoration function and 2. without the decoration function

https://i.stack.imgur.com/89Vyj.jpg

Is it possible to shrink the calendar view with the decoration like in the version without the decoration? Are there alternatives for the decoration to mark single dates so that it is still possible to shrink the height?

```
struct CalendarView_UIKit: UIViewRepresentable{

    // ...

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UICalendarView {
        let view = UICalendarView()
        view.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        view.availableDateRange = interval
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        view.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
        view.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        let dateSelection = UICalendarSelectionSingleDate(delegate: context.coordinator)
        view.selectionBehavior = dateSelection
        return view
    }

    // ...


    class Coordinator: NSObject, UICalendarViewDelegate, UICalendarSelectionSingleDateDelegate{
    
        var parent: CalendarView_UIKit
    
        // ...
    
        @MainActor
        func calendarView(_ calendarView: UICalendarView, decorationFor dateComponents: DateComponents) -> UICalendarView.Decoration? {

            // ...

            return .image(UIImage(systemName: "circle.fill"))

        }
    }

}
```